# PHP - Upload image resource to FTP

Tags: php, image, upload, ftp, resources

I'm trying to resize image and upload it to FTP server without saving it on local disc but I didn't find any method how to do that. Function ftp_fput obviously doesn't TAKE image resource as argument.

I'm trying to do this:

```
imagecopyresampled($canvas, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $oldWidth, $oldHeight);

ob_start();
imagejpeg($canvas);
$stream = ob_get_clean();

// ftp_->fput(imagecreatefromstring($stream));
ftp_->fput($stream);
```

Any help?

Comment: Any reason you don't want to save to temp directory upload then delete the file/use a cron job to clean up the old images?

Comment: If your server supports it you may be able to use the [ftp stream wrapper](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ftp.php) to write a string to a file on a remote server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP doesn't have a function to write a string through ftp. You would have to write the file to disk and send it or you can use the `php://memory` or `php://temp` wrapper to write the data to memory and pass that to `ftp_fput`. There is a comment on the [ftp_put](http://www.php.net/ftp_put) manual page that has a simple function that flushes to a temp file.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php#83260

There are a few comments on the [ftp_fput](http://www.php.net/ftp_fput) manual page that cover this as well.